# PhpExcel many columns causes the file to be broken

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am generating an excel file using phpexcel, the columns are 186 so I have created an array of the header columns and dynamically adding them

```
            $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
            $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
            $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
            $sheet->setTitle(lang('invoices'));
            $col ='A1';
            foreach($columns as $key => $value){
                $sheet->setCellValue($col,  $value);
                ++$col; //in a loop;
            }
```

the file is created well but the columns are broken as seen in the picture below. anyone ever encountered this issue?

[image]

**UPDATING THE QUESTION**

Now the xcel sheet has over 150 columns but not all of them are to be filled with data. only like 15 columns are to be put data.

Iam looping my db result but when inserts the sheet comes with jumping data. here is how I insert the data.

```
     $row = 0;
            foreach ($data as $data_row) {
                $sheet->setCellValue('A1'. $row, '0');
                $sheet->setCellValue('B1'. $row, $data_row->id);
                $sheet->setCellValue('C1'. $row, $data_row->customer_id);
                $sheet->setCellValue('D1' . $row, $data_row->invoice_id);
                $sheet->setCellValue('E1' . $row, $data_row->invoice_details);
                $sheet->setCellValue('F1' . $row, $data_row->account_set);
                $sheet->setCellValue('G1' . $row, $data_row->issue_date);
                $sheet->setCellValue('H1' . $row, 'TAS');
                $sheet->setCellValue('I1' . $row, $this->sma->formatNo($data_row->currency_rate));
                $sheet->setCellValue('J1' . $row, $this->sma->formatDecimal($data_row->grand_total));
                $sheet->setCellValue('K1' . $row, $this->sma->formatDecimal($data_row->invoice_tax));
                $sheet->setCellValue('L1' . $row, $this->sma->formatDecimal($data_row->grand_total));
                $sheet->setCellValue('M1' . $row, $this->sma->formatDecimal($data_row->grand_total));
                $sheet->setCellValue('M1' . $row, $this->sma->formatDecimal($data_row->invoice_tax));
                $sheet->setCellValue('N1' . $row, $this->sma->formatDecimal($data_row->grand_total));
                $sheet->setCellValue('O1' . $row, $this->sma->formatDecimal($data_row->grand_total));
                $sheet->setCellValue('P1' . $row, $this->sma->formatDecimal($data_row->invoice_tax));
                if ($data_row->source_type == SHIPMENT)
                    $sheet->setCellValue('E1' . $row, 'Newspaper distribution on ' . $this->sma->hrsd($data_row->issue_date) . ' to ' . $data_row->route_name);
                $row++;
            }
```

and here is the end result of data

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a PHPExcel or a PhpSpreadsheet issue: what's happening here is that you're misunderstanding how the PHP increment operator works with a string value that contains mixed alpha and numeric characters.

Take a look at the output from your increment when there's no reference to PHPExcel or PhpSpreadsheet to see what's happening here:

```php
$col ='A1';
for($x = 0; $x <= 12; ++$x){
    echo $col, PHP_EOL;
    ++$col; //in a loop;
}
```

PHP increments the numeric character until it reaches the size limit for that numeric (1 digit, so 1 through 9). It then resets the digit to 0,and increments the alpha (so 'A' becomes 'B'), and subsequent increments will increment the numeric again until it reaches 9, then it will reset the numeric back to 0 and increment the alpha again:

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
A6
A7
A8
A9
B0
B1
B2
B3
```

Either set the column to `A` and concatenate with a hard-coded row `1`

```php
$col ='A';
foreach($columns as $key => $value){
    $sheet->setCellValue($col . '1',  $value);
    ++$col; //in a loop;
}
```

or make use of PhpSpreadsheet's `fromArray()` method to populate the whole row from the array that you already have

Comment: Thanks so much for this very helpful answer. I have applied as you suggests and it'w working well. I also encounter another issue when populating data in the sheet, it leaves a couple rows empty (10 to start) then keeps jumping rows

Comment: @NaszNjokaSr. Well without seeing what the rest of your code is doing, it's not easy to offer any help

Comment: Ok I will update the question but the idea is that I am generating an excel sheet with many columns but only a few of them are to be filled by array pulled from db. so when I do so the excel keeps having gaps in rows.  what I do is run.    $row = 0;
                foreach ($data as $data_row) {
                    $sheet->setCellValue('A1'. $row, '0'); //etc                                              }

Answer (score 1):

Your second problem is a basic problem with understanding what the concatenation operator (`.`) does in PHP.

You are concatenating a cell address (`A1`) with a row value (starting with `0`)

```php
'A1'. $row
```

This will give a result of `A10`, so the cell reference is cell `A10`. When the value of `$row` is `9`, concatenation will give cell `A19`; and when `$row` is next incremented to `10` the concatenation will give cell `A110`, etc.

First set `$row` to be the actual first row where you want the data populating:

```php
     $row = 2;
```

Then concatenate a column (e.g. `A`) with the row number rather than concatenating a cell address with the row number:

```php
foreach ($data as $data_row) {
    $sheet->setCellValue('A'. $row, '0');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B'. $row, $data_row->id);
    $sheet->setCellValue('C'. $row, $data_row->customer_id);
    $sheet->setCellValue('D' . $row, $data_row->invoice_id);
    $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $row, $data_row->invoice_details);
    $sheet->setCellValue('F' . $row, $data_row->account_set);
    $sheet->setCellValue('G' . $row, $data_row->issue_date);
    $sheet->setCellValue('H' . $row, 'TAS');
    $sheet->setCellValue('I' . $row, $this->sma->formatNo($data_row->currency_rate));
    $sheet->setCellValue('J' . $row, $this->sma->formatDecimal($data_row->grand_total));
    $sheet->setCellValue('K' . $row, $this->sma->formatDecimal($data_row->invoice_tax));
    $sheet->setCellValue('L' . $row, $this->sma->formatDecimal($data_row->grand_total));
    $sheet->setCellValue('M' . $row, $this->sma->formatDecimal($data_row->grand_total));
    $sheet->setCellValue('M' . $row, $this->sma->formatDecimal($data_row->invoice_tax));
    $sheet->setCellValue('N' . $row, $this->sma->formatDecimal($data_row->grand_total));
    $sheet->setCellValue('O' . $row, $this->sma->formatDecimal($data_row->grand_total));
    $sheet->setCellValue('P' . $row, $this->sma->formatDecimal($data_row->invoice_tax));
    if ($data_row->source_type == SHIPMENT)
        $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $row, 'Newspaper distribution on ' . $this->sma->hrsd($data_row->issue_date) . ' to ' . $data_row->route_name);
    $row++;
}
```

so then the concatenation for the first cell address will be `A` . `2` giving cell `A2`.

And in anticipation of the third problem, you are writing two different values in Columns `E` and `M`: the second value in each case will overwrite the first value.

Please take some time to read the PHP documentation and learn the language

Comment: thanks for the help. I will definitely check on string concatenation